# Merge unallocated disk space into ubuntu partition

Tags: 10.10

Trying to merge unallocated space 55.3 GB with Ubuntu in ext4 (58.35GB) to hopefully get a new partition with around 113 GB. having much difficulty. Any help greatly appreciated. screenshot provided. many thanks!

Comment: tried using gpart without much success. cant put up a screenshot - need 10 posts or replies

Answer (score 1):

If your 58.35 GB partition (ext4) is the system root partition, or your /home, or your /boot partition, you can't modify it when the system is running. That's because you have to unmount the patition you want to resize.
If that's your case, you can use a live CD or live USB linux distribution and run a partition manager program. I think the best choise is GParted Live. It is a linux distro based on Debian. When you boot it, it automatically runs a partition manager called GParted.

This is the GParted official Website:

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

NOTE:
You can use an Ubuntu Live CD (or another live distro) too. You just have to install, for example, GParted on it and you will have the same partition manager program.

But if your ext4 patition doesn't have system files, you can unmount it and use Gparted (by installing it from the Ubuntu Software Center) to resize it.

Sorry for my extremly poor english.

Regards!

Ariel